# Sql query update and set

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update some values in a table via MySQL and php, but I cannot it to work: Here is my code:

```
$update = "UPDATE $table 
           SET `active`='1' AND `title`='Disabled By Moderator' 
           WHERE `id`='".$ad_id."' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Before asking Question to **SO** you should have tried studying **update syntax.** and you would have solved it in **less than 30 secs.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when updating multiple columns, separated it with a comma.

```
$update = "UPDATE $table SET `active`='1' , `title`='Disabled By Moderator' WHERE `id`='".$ad_id."' LIMIT 1";
```

the reason why it is updating `1` or `0` on column `active` is because the statement is performing boolean operation. The only column that is affected on your current statement is only column `Active`. Column `title` is part of the boolean operation.

Your update statement will look like if it is grouped,

```
UPDATE $table 
SET    active = (1 AND (title = 'Disabled By Moderator'))
WHERE  id= 'val' 
LIMIT  1
```

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Wow thanks for the reply in less then 1 min :D You rock!

Comment: updated the answer with some additional info.

Comment: It's very important to perform [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or very bad things will happen.